# Ruby on rails, when query mysql database, always return an empty array

Tags: javascript, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to do a get request to read data from mysql database. Code is as below. The Ajax request is completed, but the returned data is always an empty array no matter I add select or not. I am pretty sure there should be some data. In the log, `name`, `type` and `id` are passed correctly. And similar request works for other actions. Some one has any idea what could be wrong? Thanks.

In controller:

```
def find_data
  name = params[:name]
  ty = params[:ty]
  val = params[:val]
 
  # @query_data = MyDB.select(:List).where(Name: name, Ty: ty, Val: val)
  @query_data = MyDB.where(Name: name, Ty: ty, Val: val)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json{ render json: @query_data}
  end
end
```

In javascript:

```
function find_data() {

  var name = $('#name_select').val();
  var ty = $('#ty_select').val();
  var val = value;

  $.ajax({
    url: '/home/find_data';,
    type: 'get',
    data: {'name' : name,
          'ty' : ty,
          'val' : val},
        
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);

  }).fail( function(data) {
    console.log('Ajax request failed');
  });
  
}
```

Comment: `:name : name, :ty : ty, :val : val` is not valid Ruby, we need to see your actual code to help you.

Comment: @smathy, ahha,  there is no `:` before variable, should be MyDB.where(Name : name, Ty : ty, Val : val), Name, Ty, and Val are the columns.

Comment: So, add in a `Rails.logger.debug params` to your `find_data` method, and then show the output of that from your logs AND the output of running the same `MyDB.where` in a rails console with the values from that hash as logged substituted into the query.

Comment: Yea, I did this, the `logger.debug params.inspect` gives the correct data, but the `MyDB.where` returns `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>` which is not expected, there should be some data in DB @smathy

Comment: I think if `find_data` you should `MyDB.where("name LIKE  ? OR ty LIKE ? OR val LIKE ?", "%#{name}%", "%#{ty}%", "%#{val}%")`. As you `MyDB.where(Name: name, Ty: ty, Val: val)` just return 1 result if query (name, ty, value) have (true, false, false),  (true, true, false),  (false, true, true),  (false, true, false), ... => data = [] else query (name, ty, value) have (true, true, true) => data = [{name: "a", ty: "...', value: "..."}]

Comment: Ok, so obviously the data isn't as you assumed it was, good lesson here - always confirm your assumptions in the rails console.

Comment: Yes, I remove one condition, and it return the data, but not sure why that condition doesn't work, since all rows in the column have the same value in that column. @smathy

Comment: @LihnNguyen yea, I want them to equal the values.

Comment: Obviously, the value is not what you think it is.  Maybe a leading/trailing space, maybe a charset issue, maybe just PEBKAC :)